# php imap_getmailboxes security error

Tags: php, imap

I have previously written several scripts to manage IMAP - for example, removing all emails marked as spam.  I'm now trying to write a more general script that examines the mailboxes available.  I thought I would start with the example from the PHP web site for imap_getmailboxes.  Here is my version

```
$user = 'someuser';
$pass = 'somepassword';
define ( '_IMAP_CONNECTION', '{localhost:7674/service=imap/notls}' );
define ( '_IMAP_USER', $user );
define ( '_IMAP_PASS', $pass );
define ( '_IMAP_DEBUG', false );

if (! _IMAP_CONNECTION || ! _IMAP_USER || ! _IMAP_PASS) {
    $message .= "Not able to make IMAP connection as one or more constants are false. (" . _IMAP_CONNECTION . "," . _IMAP_USER . "," . _IMAP_PASS . ")";
    die ( $message );
}
if (_IMAP_DEBUG) {
    echo '</strong>debug - prior imap_open ' . _IMAP_CONNECTION . ' ' . _IMAP_USER . ' ' . _IMAP_PASS;
}
$conn = @imap_open ( _IMAP_CONNECTION, _IMAP_USER, _IMAP_PASS, OP_HALFOPEN );
if (! $conn) {
    die ( "Unable to make connection due to " . imap_last_error () );
}
$list = imap_getmailboxes ( $conn, IMAP_CONNECTION, "*" );
if (is_array ( $list )) {
    foreach ( $list as $key => $val ) {
        echo "($key) ";
        echo imap_utf7_decode ( $val->name ) . ",";
        echo "'" . $val->delimiter . "',";
        echo $val->attributes . "<br />\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "imap_getmailboxes failed: " . imap_last_error () . "\n";
}
imap_close ( $conn );
```

When I try to run this I get

imap_getmailboxes failed: SECURITY PROBLEM: insecure server advertised AUTH=PLAIN

I've previously used the definition of IMAP_CONNECTION to open and manipulate INBOX but I can't find anyway to make imap_getmailboxes work.  What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

The client library which you're using refuses to send the credentials over an insecure (i.e. cleartext, with no encryption) connection. This might be a reaosnable thing to do if you're trying to connect over a public network, or it could be a useless thing if you're connecting to a server on the same machine. If you're going over the network, either connect via TLS (previously often called "SSL", often on port 993), or issue the `STARTTLS` command.

If, however, your connection is actually secure, either get another IMAP library or configure the one you're using to not care about TLS.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "_" from _IMAP_CONNECTION

```
         imap_getmailboxes ( $conn, IMAP_CONNECTION, "*" );
```

should be

```
        imap_getmailboxes ( $conn, _IMAP_CONNECTION, "*" );
```